# using wget to download xml for conky script won't keep html tags

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, wget, conky

So I'm trying to setup a conkyrc for weather, using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

station="KRAP.xml"
wdir='/tmp/weather'

update_xml() {
          if [ ! -e "$station" ]; then
                  wget -q http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/${station}
                  [ -e "$station" ] && touch "${station}"
else
    # dtime: time the .xml file was downloaded
    # otime: time the weather data was observed
    # ctime: current time (time this script is being run)
    dtime=$(stat -c %Y $station)
    otime=$(date -d "$utime" +%s)
    ctime=$(date +%s)

    if (( "$otime" + 4507 < "$ctime" )); then
        if (( "$dtime" + 307 < "$ctime" )); then
            wget -q -O "$station" http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/${station}
            [ -e "$station" ] && touch "${station}"
        fi
    fi
fi
}

from_xml() { xmllint -xpath "//$1" - <<< "$xml" | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'; }

[ -d "$wdir" ] || mkdir -p "$wdir"
cd "$wdir" || exit 1

xml=''
[ -r $station ] && xml="$(< $station)"
( update_xml >/dev/null 2>&1 ) &

if [ -n "$xml" ]; then
        location=$(from_xml "location")
        utime=$(from_xml "observation_time_rfc822")
        weather=$(from_xml "weather")
        temperature=$(from_xml "temp_f")
        humid=$(from_xml "relative_humidity")
        wind_dir=$(from_xml "wind_dir")
        case "$wind_dir" in
                "North") wind_dir="N" ;;
                "South") wind_dir="S" ;;
                "East") wind_dir="E" ;;
                "West") wind_dir="W" ;;
                "Northwest") wind_dir="NW" ;;
                "Northeast") wind_dir="NE" ;;
                "Southwest") wind_dir="SW" ;;
                "Southeast") wind_dir="SE" ;;
       esac
       wind_speed=$(from_xml "wind_kt")
       baro_pressure=$(from_xml "pressure_in")

       echo "$location"
       echo "Updated: $(date -d "$utime" 2>/dev/null )"
       printf 'Weather: %s %s°F\n' "$weather" "$temperature"
       printf 'Barometric Pressure: %s inches\n' "$baro_pressure"
       printf 'Wind: %s at %s knots\n' "$wind_dir" "$wind_speed"
       printf 'Humidity: %s%%\n' "$humid"
else
       echo "No weather data available."
fi
```

But when it downloads the xml it excludes all the identifying information so instead of downloading the source code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet href="latest_ob.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
 <current_observation version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.weather.gov/view/current_observation.xsd">
<credit>NOAA's National Weather Service</credit>
<credit_URL>http://weather.gov/</credit_URL>
<image>
    <url>http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</url>
    <title>NOAA's National Weather Service</title>
    <link>http://weather.gov</link>
</image>
<suggested_pickup>15 minutes after the hour</suggested_pickup>
<suggested_pickup_period>60</suggested_pickup_period>
<location>Rapid City, Rapid City Regional Airport, SD</location>
<station_id>KRAP</station_id>
<latitude>44.04556</latitude>
<longitude>-103.05389</longitude>
<observation_time>Last Updated on Jul 31 2015, 8:52 am MDT</observation_time>
    <observation_time_rfc822>Fri, 31 Jul 2015 08:52:00 -0600</observation_time_rfc822>
<weather>Fair</weather>
<temperature_string>72.0 F (22.2 C)</temperature_string>
<temp_f>72.0</temp_f>
<temp_c>22.2</temp_c>
<relative_humidity>52</relative_humidity>
<wind_string>North at 8.1 MPH (7 KT)</wind_string>
<wind_dir>North</wind_dir>
<wind_degrees>340</wind_degrees>
<wind_mph>8.1</wind_mph>
<wind_kt>7</wind_kt>
<pressure_string>1022.2 mb</pressure_string>
<pressure_mb>1022.2</pressure_mb>
<pressure_in>30.24</pressure_in>
<dewpoint_string>53.1 F (11.7 C)</dewpoint_string>
<dewpoint_f>53.1</dewpoint_f>
<dewpoint_c>11.7</dewpoint_c>
<visibility_mi>10.00</visibility_mi>
<icon_url_base>http://forecast.weather.gov/images/wtf/small/</icon_url_base>
<two_day_history_url>http://www.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KRAP.html</two_day_history_url>
<icon_url_name>skc.png</icon_url_name>
<ob_url>http://www.weather.gov/data/METAR/KRAP.1.txt</ob_url>
<disclaimer_url>http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html</disclaimer_url>
<copyright_url>http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html</copyright_url>
<privacy_policy_url>http://weather.gov/notice.html</privacy_policy_url>
```

It creates the xml document like this:

```
NOAA's National Weather Service
http://weather.gov/

    http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif
    NOAA's National Weather Service
    http://weather.gov

15 minutes after the hour
60
Rapid City, Rapid City Regional Airport, SD
KRAP
44.04556
-103.05389
Last Updated on Jul 31 2015, 8:52 am MDT
    Fri, 31 Jul 2015 08:52:00 -0600
Fair
72.0 F (22.2 C)
72.0
22.2
52
North at 8.1 MPH (7 KT)
North
340
8.1
7
1022.2 mb
1022.2
30.24
53.1 F (11.7 C)
53.1
11.7
10.00
 http://forecast.weather.gov/images/wtf/small/
http://www.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KRAP.html
skc.png
http://www.weather.gov/data/METAR/KRAP.1.txt
http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html
http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html
http://weather.gov/notice.html
```

It removes all the html tags and only gives the raw info. Then my script can't pull "location" because it's not identified in the xml download. I've tried using "wget -F" to force html but it doesn't make a difference. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is ok, parse is via `awk`, E.G.:

**location**

```
curl http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KRAP.xml | \
    awk -F'[<|>]' '/<location>/ {print $3}'
```

*Output*

```
Rapid City, Rapid City Regional Airport, SD
```

---

**location and weather**

```
curl http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KRAP.xml \
    | awk -F'[<|>]' '/<location>|<weather>/ {print $3}'
```

*Output*

```
Rapid City, Rapid City Regional Airport, SD
Fair
```

---

**location and weather in an other output format**

```
curl http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KRAP.xml \
    | awk -F'[<|>]' '/<location>/ {print "Location:"$3}/<weather>/ {print "Weather:"$3}'
```

*Output*

```
Location:Rapid City, Rapid City Regional Airport, SD
Weather:Fair
```